# List of ColorSpaces does not usually include PDF ColorSpaces?

Tags: color, pdf, color-spaces

Why would a (complete) list of ColorSpaces, like the one in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_color_spaces_and_their_uses), ignore the 11 color spaces used in the [PDF file format](https://www.prepressure.com/pdf/basics/color)?

Device dependent color spaces:

1. DeviceGray
2. DeviceRGB
3. DeviceCMYK

Device independent color spaces:

4. CalGray
5. CalRGB
6. Lab
7. ICCBased

Special:

8. Indexed
9. Pattern
10. Separation
11. DeviceN

Answer (score 0):

They explain  [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_color_spaces_and_their_uses#RGB_2) and [3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_color_spaces_and_their_uses#CMYK_2). they don't list grayscale as a color space because its not really a color space, its lack of color. Note they do explain 1 under [grayscale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale) and [black and white](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_and_white).

> 4. CalGray 5. CalRGB 6. Lab 7. ICCBased

These arent really color spaces, but rather spaces with calibration. They do list several of the calibration spaces though and explain teh context under individual spaces, as well as explain icc profiles. Here they are being somewhat inconsistent though.

> 5. Indexed

Indexed isn't a color space but a compression/encoding scheme. It still uses a underlying space which wikipedia lists.

> 9. Pattern 10. Separation

These are not colorspaces as such

> 11. DeviceN

Okay this I agree they could list. Although it would probably need to be called something else.

Comment: would you elaborate on why a "space with calibration" is not a color space? On "Indexed", "Pattern" and "Separation". These are all listed by Adobe as color spaces used in PDF, see section 8.6 of the Adobe Reference Manual https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/PDF32000_2008.pdf

Comment: @PauloNey its a programming language of sorts  they have just extended the existing tag. It does not need to have a scientific basis.  "space with calibration" is not a colorspace bacuse its a space exactly like device RGB, device CMYK or device Grayscale. We just know what the name or the description of the space is. Its still just a Grayscale, RGB or CMYK space and has exactly the same properties just now with a global meaning.